# Как вынести в модуль пакет библиотеки, не перемещая сам код библиотеки?

Tags: android, gradle, модули

Всем привет. В проекте имеется локально добавленная библиотека `RecyclerView`, в которую разработчики добавили от себя фичи. Находится пакет в главном модуле. Я разрабатываю мультимодульный форк на основе этого проекта и мне понадобилось использовать этот кастомный `RecyclerView` в своём отдельном модуле. Но я не могу обращаться к основному модулю из подключаемого к нему.

Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему, не копируя эту библиотеку в свой модуль? Например, как-то подключить этот пакет в своём модуле или как-то ещё.

Сейчас я пробую это сделать через добавление этого кода в `srcDirs` внутри `build.gradle` своего модуля:

```
sourceSets.main.java {
    srcDirs += '../app/src/main/java'
    exclude '...?'
}
```

Как я понимаю, это и есть то, что мне нужно, но у меня не получается забрать только определенный пакет - `androidx` из каталога `java`. В моём модуле появляются все пакеты основного модуля, включая не нужный мне `com` и у меня не получается прописать путь для него в `exclude`. Если же я пробую добавить путь к `androidx` в `srcDirs`, то в моём модуле появляется пакет `recyclerview` (который внутри `androidx`), т.е. ломается структура импортированного кода.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, туда ли я вообще копаю?